# Python Array Index - Every X elements?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, lambda, indexing

So I have a weird problem...

I'd like to process an array and take naturally rounded indices's out of it.

For example, if you have array...

```
pies = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I'd like to take every 1.1st element out of it rounded naturally. So under this case:

```
pies[0::round(1.1x)]
```

Would output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Because it would take out the following rounded positions:

```
pies[0]->pies[0]
pies[1.1]->pies[1]
pies[2.2]->pies[2]
pies[3.3]->pies[3]
pies[4.4]->pies[4]
pies[5.5]->pies[6]
pies[6.6]->pies[7]
pies[7.7]->pies[8]
pies[8.8]->pies[9]
```

Note we're not rounding the content - we're rounding the index.

As another example, consider:

```
pies = [0, 2, 5, 1, 3, 9, 2, 12, 33, 45]
pies[0::round(1.1x)]
```

Would output:

```
[0, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 12, 33, 45]
```

I'm wondering how you could do this in the most 'pythonic' way possible.

Thanks!

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @miindlek Sorry. I'll edit that in. I'm wondering how you'd accomplish this in the most pythonic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [7]: pies = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [8]: stride=1.1

In [9]: [pies[x] for x in range(len(pies)) for x in [int(round(x*stride))] if x < len(pies)]
Out[9]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In the alternative, this seems like a good job for a generator function:

```
def rounding_iterator(seq, stride):
    try:
        i = 0
        while True:
            yield seq[int(round(i*stride))]
            i += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass


pies = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print list(rounding_iterator(pies, 1))
print list(rounding_iterator(pies, 1.1))
print list(rounding_iterator(pies, .9))
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Awesome! This is the one I'm accepting as the answer as it takes into consideration going over the length. Thanks so much everyone! Love the python stackoverflow crowd~.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited this, so you need increment index with 1.1 and round it. Correct?

If so, it should be something like this:

```
>>> pies = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 77, 88, 99]
>>> print [ pies[int(round(x*0.1+x))] for x in xrange(len(pies)-1) ]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 77, 88, 99]

>>> pies = [0, 2, 5, 1, 3, 9, 2, 12, 33, 45]
>>> print [ pies[int(round(x*0.1+x))] for x in xrange(len(pies)-1) ]
[0, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 12, 33, 45]
>>>
```

Does this, what you want?

Same with numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> pies = [0, 2, 5, 1, 3, 9, 2, 12, 33, 45]
>>> print [ pies[int(round(x))] for x in np.arange(0,len(pies)-1,1.1) ]
[0, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 12, 33, 45]
```

With numpy you can change multiplier:

```
>>> print [ pies[int(round(x))] for x in np.arange(0,len(pies)/1.1,1.1) ]
[0, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 12, 33, 45]
>>> print [ pies[int(round(x))] for x in np.arange(0,len(pies)/3.3,3.3) ]
[0]
>>> print [ pies[int(round(x))] for x in np.arange(0,len(pies)/2.2,2.2) ]
[0, 5, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: That doesn't get me the xth elements though. You seem to be multiplying the content and then rounding it. I would like the index itself multiplied and rounded.

Comment: @VardaElbereth it actually does this. Try print [ ( x,int(round(x)) ) for x in np.arange(0,len(pies)-1,1.1) ]

Comment: What happens if `len(pies) == 20`?

Comment: @rth Actually, there's one last problem. Currently there's an index out of range error if you change the multiplier. Change it to 0.3 for example.

Comment: @VardaElbereth I've added answer to my post.

Answer (score 0):

How about multiplying the value in the list by 1.1, rounding it, and converting it to an int to drop the decimal:

```
pies = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for pie in pies:
    print int(round(pie * 1.1))
```

Comment: I'm not explaining this properly. I don't care about the value itself. I'd like to get every xth element with a rounded index value. The content in the array should remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be one line...

```
def rounded_indices(ls):
    result = []
    original_index = 0
    new_index = 0
    while new_index < len(ls):
        result.append(ls[new_index])
        original_index += 1
        new_index = int(round(1.1 * original_index))

    return result

>>> pies = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> rounded_indices(pies)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```